# Using pyOpenSSL to generate a p12 using a passphrase text file

Tags: python, openssl, pyopenssl

Is there a way to provide a passphrase via a text file when creating a p12 file using pyOpenSSL?

For example when using Openssl on the command line I would pass the argument `-passout file:passphrase.txt` to `openssl pkcs12`, but in the documentation for pyOpenSSL I can see that the export method only allows for the passphrase to be provided as a string: https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#pkcs12-objects

Comment: why cant you just open the text file, read its contents, then depending if its multi-lined in the file or not, concatenate to a string?

Comment: I have a program that requires both the p12 file and the corresponding passphrase text file. For some reason if I do what you suggest then the program says the p12 file is "misconfigured".. even though the passphrase stored in the p12 is the same as the one in the passphrase text file. @Noah